# Можно ли тегу img задать class?

Tags: html, сss3

Можно ли тегу img задать class?

Comment: Можно, а иногда даже нужно

Comment: class можно задавать вообще любому тегу

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, но затрудняюсь назвать причину...  ))

Answer (score 1):

Любому тегу можно задать класс. В том числе и img

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.
`<img class="" src="" alt=""/>`